# Can a metric space consist only of one point and is it complete?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Can metric space consists only of 0 as one element?

I think Yes, because we can take standard metric and all of axioms are done.

$d(0,0) =0$;

$d(0,0) = d(0,0) = 0$;

$d(0,0) \le d(0,0) + d(0,0)$

is it true?

Comment: I need this because, I want to construct complete metric space X such that for all x,y from X: d(x,y) belong to Q

Comment: Yes, it's a metric space and is complete (any finite metric space is complete).

Comment: Yep, thanks, and another question: can we construct infinite complete space X such that for all x,y from X: d(x,y) belong to Q(rational numbers)?

Comment: Yes. (think of some subset in $\mathbb R$)

Comment: Or think about the most trivial of all metrics.

Comment: Is it true that any space with discrete metric is complete? d(x,A) = 1 if d x != A

Comment: Yes, try to prove it....

Comment: so the answers for for my question is: take any subset of R and discrete metric, so d(x,y) belong to Q and it is complete space?

Comment: @JonathanTaylor consider what sort of sequences the discrete metric can have.